# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when creating directory

Tags: c, directory, segmentation-fault

I have this simple code:

```
int read_data(int GrNr) {
    //many lines of code
    fprintf(fdatagroup, "%i", Ngroups);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for(NUM=NUM_MIN;NUM<=NUM_MAX;NUM++) {
        sprintf(groupfile,"../output/profiles/properties_%03d.txt", NUM);
        fdatagroup = fopen(groupfile,"w");

        GROUP=0;
        accept=0;

        do {
            check=read_data(GROUP);
            printf("check = %d \n", check);

            accept++;
            FOF_GROUP++;
        }
        while (accept<=n_of_halos);

        fclose(fdatagroup);
    }
    printf("Everything done.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If I don't create manually the folder called "profiles" inside my output directory i get 
the error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

If the folder is there, everything works fine.
What can I do to be able to create the directory from inside the code?
I am using gcc in linux.
Thanks.

Comment: See: [mkdir](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mkdir.2.html)

Comment: I *hate* it when people don't check for errors in `fopen()` :(

Answer (score 1):

Just as some background, when fopen attempts to open a file that does not exist, instead of failing, it simply returns NULL.  The seg fault then occurs when you try to read/write data to a null pointer.

The creation and destruction of directories lies within the realm of sys/dir.h

```
#include <sys/dir.h>
...
mkdir(path_str);
```

Comment: And please, if you don't like mysterious segment faults also use snprintf() rather than sprintf(). And the same for ever function you call that fills your buffers.

Comment: Could you explain me a bit what you mean by that? What is the difference and how does it help me?

Comment: His problem isn't `sprintf`...plus, if you are printing only numbers, you can guarantee that the output string will not be more than 16 characters longer per number output.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

mkdir("/path/to/dir", 0777); // second argument is new file mode for directory (as in chmod)
```

You should also *always* check your functions for failure. `fopen` returns NULL and sets `errno` if it fails to open the file; `mkdir` (and most other system calls returning `int`) returns `-1` and sets `errno`. You can use `perror` to print out a message containing the error string:

```
#include <errno.h>

if(mkdir("/path", 0777) < 0 && errno != EEXIST) { // we check for EEXIST since maybe the directory is already there
    perror("mkdir failed");
    exit(-1); // or some other error handling code
}
```